# Javascript - Pushing pageview to Google Analytics when using Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, infinite-scroll

I have short question. I have an issue with making my push of a pageview when using infinite scroll.

Here is my script:

```
<script>
        $('.page-section').jscroll({
            autotrigger: true,
            loadingHtml: '<img class="center-block" src="/images/712.gif" alt="Loading" />',
            padding: 20,
            nextSelector: 'a.next',
            contentSelector: '.col-md-3, .pagination'
        }, function(){
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $('a.next').attr('href')]);
        });
</script>
```

Infinite scrolling is working, but the page views are not. I'm not sure if I am pushing the values correctly via _gaq.push

Comment: Are You really using old google analytics code?

Comment: Exactly the issue... should have used: ga('send', 'pageview',etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was the correct version:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', $('a.next').attr('href'));
```